# Python operations

Tags: python, python-2.7

> in this mission you should implement some boolean operations:
>
> - "conjunction" denoted x ∧ y, satisfies x ∧ y = 1 if x = y = 1 and x ∧ y = 0 otherwise.
> - "disjunction" denoted x ∨ y, satisfies x ∨ y = 0 if x = y = 0 and x ∨ y = 1 otherwise.
> - "implication" (material implication) denoted x→y and can be described as ¬ x ∨ y. If x is true then the value of x → y is taken to be that of y. But if x is false then the value of y can be ignored; however the operation must return some truth value and there are only two choices, so the return value is the one that entails less, namely true.
> - "exclusive" (exclusive or) denoted x ⊕ y and can be described as (x ∨ y)∧ ¬ (x ∧ y). It excludes the possibility of both x and y. Defined in terms of arithmetic it is addition mod 2 where 1 + 1 = 0.
> - "equivalence" denoted x ≡ y and can be described as ¬ (x ⊕ y). It's true just when x and y have the same value.
>
> Here you can see the truth table for these operations:
>
> ```
>     x | y | x∧y | x∨y | x→y | x⊕y | x≡y |
>     --------------------------------------
>     0 | 0 |  0  |  0  |  1  |  0  |  1  |
>     1 | 0 |  0  |  1  |  0  |  1  |  0  |
>     0 | 1 |  0  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  0  |
>     1 | 1 |  1  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  1  |
>     --------------------------------------
> ```
>
> You are given two boolean values x and y as 1 or 0 and you are given an operation name as described earlier. You should calculate the value and return it as 1 or 0.

Here is my code so far:

```
OPERATION_NAMES = ("conjunction", "disjunction", "implication", "exclusive", "equivalence")

def boolean(x, y, operation):
if (x and y) == 0:
    return 0
elif (x or y) == 1:
    return 1 



if __name__ == '__main__':
    #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert boolean(1, 0, u"conjunction") == 0, "and"
    assert boolean(1, 0, u"disjunction") == 1, "or"
    assert boolean(1, 1, u"implication") == 1, "material"
    assert boolean(0, 1, u"exclusive") == 1, "xor"
    assert boolean(0, 1, u"equivalence") == 0, "same?"
```

The first if is working I got a problem with completing disjunction and the other operations!Can some1 help me please?

Comment: Anything more specific than *"got a problem"*?

Comment: Yes I don't know how should i do the rest of the operations

Comment: *"I don't know how"* isn't an [on-topic question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Where is your attempt, and what precisely is wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a *dictionary* mapping from name to operation. Use *bitwise* operations as your operands are integer values 1 and 0:

```
ops = {
    'conjunction': lambda a, b: a & b,
    'disjunction': lambda a, b: a | b,
    # ... etc.
}
def boolean(a, b, operation):
    return ops[operation](a, b)
```

The conjunction, disjunction and exclusive operations can also be handled by the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html). Equivalence is just equality, so `operator.eq` can handle that:

```
import operator

ops = {
    'conjunction': operator.and_,
    'disjunction': operator.or_,
    'exclusive': operator.xor,
    'equivalence': operator.eq,
}
```

This leaves you with having to implement `implication` yourself. However, the text already gives you a handy implementation guide:

> can be described as ¬ x ∨ y

so the lambda would be:

```
lambda a, b: (1 - a) | b
```

using `1 - a` to simulate NOT.

Complete solution:

```
import operator

ops = {
    'conjunction': operator.and_,
    'disjunction': operator.or_,
    'implication': lambda a, b: (1 - a) | b,
    'exclusive': operator.xor,
    'equivalence': operator.eq,
}
def boolean(a, b, operation):
    return ops[operation](a, b)
```

Comment: so how would u do exclusive and implication?

Comment: @Martjin Pieters why disjunction says invalid syntax?

Comment: @ferarimaliferari: because commas were missing, now added.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters I am getting invaled syntax error on 'conjuction' and 'disjunction'

Comment: @ferarimaliferari: The `operator` functions `and_` and `or_` use an underscore in their name to avoid clashing with the keywords `and` and `or`. In typing up the answer I forgot to add those, since corrected.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters thx man! Done it under your post another working solution

Comment: @ferarimaliferari: you can use `==` and `^` for equivalence and exclusive, respectively, if you want to go with only lambdas.

Comment: @Martjin Pieters can I contact you somewhere?

Comment: @ferarimaliferari: sorry, I don't have any recommendations; I haven't used or helped anyone use such websites to be of any help there.

Answer (score 0):

```
OPERATION_NAMES = ("conjunction", "disjunction", "implication", "exclusive", "equivalence")
import operator
ops = {
   'conjunction': lambda x, y: x & y,
   'disjunction': lambda x, y: x | y,
   'implication': lambda x, y: (1 - x) | y,
   'exclusive': operator.xor,
   'equivalence': operator.eq,
}
def boolean(x, y, operation):
return ops[operation](x, y)



if __name__ == '__main__':
#These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
assert boolean(1, 0, u"conjunction") == 0, "and"
assert boolean(1, 0, u"disjunction") == 1, "or"
assert boolean(1, 1, u"implication") == 1, "material"
assert boolean(0, 1, u"exclusive") == 1, "xor"
assert boolean(0, 1, u"equivalence") == 0, "same?"
```

This is the working solution for this